# Which cars can have a race roll cage installed?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've noticed whilst playing that different cars have different levels of customisation.

With the [Dewbauchee Massacro](http://gta.wikia.com/Massacro) I was able to put a race roll cage into the vehicle.

Which other cars will take a race roll cage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the cars/vehicles that I know allow a *racing roll-cage* or a *general roll-cage* upgrade:

**Race Roll Cage:**

- Annis Elegy RH8

[image: Annis Elegy RH8 with roll cage]

- Benefactor Panto

[image: Benefactor Panto with roll cage]

- Benefactor Schwartzer

[image: Benefactor Schwartzer with roll cage]

- Bravado Youga (seriously)

[image: Bravado Youga with roll cage]

- Bravado Buffalo (single-player, Franklin's only)

[image: Bravado Buffalo with roll cage]

- Declasse Sabre Turbo

[image: Declasse Sabre Turbo with roll cage]

- Declasse Vigero

[image: Declasse Vigero with roll cage]

- Dewbauchee Massacro

[image: Dewbauchee Massacro with roll cage]

- Inverto Coquette

[image: Inverto Coquette with roll cage]

- Karin Futo

[image: Karin Futo with roll cage]

- Karin Sultan

[image: Karin Sultan with roll cage]

- Maibatsu Penumbra

[image: Maibatsu Penumbra with roll cage]

- Pegassi Vacca

[image: Pegassi Vacca with roll cage]

- Pfister Comet

[image: Pfister Comet with roll cage]

- Ubermacht Sentinel XS

[image: Ubermacht Sentinel XS with roll cage]

- Ubermacht Zion

[image: Ubermacht Zion with roll cage]

**General Roll Cage:**

- Canis Bodhi

[image: Canis Bodhi with roll cage]

- Karin Rebel

[image: Karin Rebel with roll cage]

Did I miss any others?

Comment: You've missed the one I included in my question ;)

Comment: Benefactor Panta...

Comment: Updated the list!

Comment: The armored kuruma also starts with a rollcage directly, but is only available online I think.